# How to install software to OS on other disk?

Tags: installation, raid, mdadm

Have installed 13.10 on a RAID1 array following this guide:

http://www.michielovertoom.com/linux/ubuntu-software-raid/

Everything went fine, except for the last step where I'm supposed to install mdadm to the new installation.

When I run apt-get (with the mounted RAID array as root-dir) it seems that it's not able to locate the ubuntu servers.
In fact I'm not able to reach the Internet in any way from the terminal I've chroot-ed to the new installation on the RAID array.

Since it's kinda important that mdadm is installed on the RAID, how do I resolve this?
Haven't found anything useful at google yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to configure software RAID 1 try with any SERVER edition, recently i tried to configure RAID 1 on 10.10 Desktop edition, failed many times, finally tried with server edition, easily can configure raid at the time of installation.